# Joomla after save menu item event or some other approach how to get actual saved menu item in admin

Tags: events, joomla, menuitem

Is there any way how to get menu item after this menu item has been saved in backend of the joomla (2.5) application. I mean something like event after save of article or category (onContentAfterSave) but after save menu item.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use the form events (that happen on any jform save) if that gets the data you want.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but i cant find any informations about form events. Can you please give me some reference?

Comment: Sorry, I should have looked it up first, menus is off in its own world, so you get the prepare events but  it doesn't even have postSaveHook. I know I've seen people deal with this problem before though.

Comment: So two things, for the general problem of modifying data I did find this http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-override-the-default-save-method-in-a-joomla-component.  I do have an idea for you but can you tell me if you you want to do this for all menu items or just specific types? It's going to sound odd but basically what you might do is modify the form (since you do have the prepare events) and use that to modify the field to do what you want. But how I'd do that would depend on the actual task you are doing and if you want it everywhere.

Comment: @Elin do you still have an idea? in my own case, I need to save html with menu output after any menu change (for integrating header with forum, but without loading the whole Joomla framework just for that).

Comment: I'm really confused about what it is you are trying to do. It's probably me being dense but what html output are you talking about?

Comment: @Elin I just wanted to explain my use case, since you asked the same OP, but I will do a hacky workaround for now, until onContentAfterSave() doesn't start to get executed for menu items as well, apparently it's either supposed to work or it would eb a good thing to add. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `com_menus/controller/item->save()` or the `com_menus/models/item->save()` methods there are no trigger events that you could work with.

If you can provide more details of what you want to do with it there may be another way to solve your problem.